# DirectX Device CAPS

Tags: c++, directx, directx-10, directx-11

I read the following in the DirectX 10 documentation:

"Legacy hardware capability bits (caps) have been removed in favor of a rich set of guaranteed functionality, which targets Direct3D 10-class hardware (minimum)."

"Removal of CAPS bits - Direct3D 10's base feature set is guaranteed."

Where do I find a list of the "guaranteed functionality / base feature set" that they talk about?

For example, under DirectX 9 I can look at D3DCAPS9.MaxTextureWidth to find the maximum texture width. How do I know the maximum size that all DirectX 10 devices must support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no more caps, so you just have to assume that your hardware (provided it's DX10 compliant) will support [the full set of DX 10 functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc308052%28VS.85%29.aspx).

This means, for example, that it is guaranteed to support 8192^2 texture sizes.  3D textures must support 2048^3.

However, be aware that hardware is allowed to implement this in software - it has to support the feature, but there are no speed guarantees.

Answer (score 3):

The minimums are available here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc308052.aspx

As you can see from that link the max texture U/V dimensions that a card must support is at LEAST 8192x8192.